# Adaptive card display is not as expected. (We are expecting the card to display data in Tabular format)

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

We are expecting the adaptive card to display data in a proper Tabular format. But since the 10 columns, the column widths are getting reduced and the text is getting wrapped. But we expect a clear view of data in table format with proper widths. We are using version 1.3 of adaptive cards.

[image]

We tried representing the data from a json response into a table format using adaptive card version 1.3. We are getting a table in a compressed (column widths) view. We are expecting a clear view of data in table format with proper widths and spacing.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [adaptive cards schema](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Table.html), the **Tables** format was introduced in Adaptive Cards Version 1.5. It will therefore not be available in a v1.3 card.

Furthermore, not every channel supports v1.5. For example, Bot Framework emulator and Web Chat have not yet been updated for v1.5 support. If the final channel you deploy to has not been updated, you might need to explore an alternative formatting method for your information.

Comment: We want the adaptive card to be displayed in Microsoft Teams. Please help in getting the clear view of data in tabular format. Currently, in the code of Adaptive card We have used columnsets and columns for getting the tabular format.

Comment: You need to test in Teams then. You won't be able to test a Table in the Emulator. It's best practice to try out your bot in a test environment in the channel you intend to deploy on.